# await without ConfigureAwait(false) continues on a different thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await

I have a WinForms app, and I have some code that needs to run on the UI thread. However, the code after the `await` runs on a different thread.

```
protected override async void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);

    // This runs on the UI thread.
    mainContainer.Controls.Clear();

    var result = await DoSomethingAsync();

    // This also needs to run on the UI thread, but it does not.
    // Instead it throws an exception:
    // "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'mainContainer' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"
    mainContainer.Controls.Add(new Control());
}
```

I also tried explicitly adding `ConfigureAwait(true)`, but it makes no difference. My understanding was that if I omit `ConfigureAwait(false)`, then the continuation should run on the original thread. Is this incorrect in some situations?

I've also noticed that if I add a control to the collection before the await, then the continuation magically runs on the correct thread.

```
protected override async void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);

    // This runs on the UI thread.
    mainContainer.Controls.Add(new Control());
    mainContainer.Controls.Clear();

    var result = await DoSomethingAsync();

    // This also runs on the UI thread now. Why?
    mainContainer.Controls.Add(new Control());
}
```

My question is:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I convince the continuation to run on the UI thread (ideally without doing my hack of adding a control and removing it)?

For reference, here are the important parts of `DoSomethingAsync`. It submits an HTTP request using RestSharp.

```
protected async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    IRestRequest request = CreateRestRequest();

    // Here I await the response from RestSharp.
    // Client is an IRestClient instance.
    // I have tried removing the ConfigureAwait(false) part, but it makes no difference.
    var response = await Client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Error)
        throw new Exception(response.ErrorMessage ?? "The request did not complete successfully.");

    if (response.StatusCode >= HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        throw new Exception("Server responded with an error: " + response.StatusCode);

    // I also do some processing of the response here; omitted for brevity.
    // There are no more awaits.
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this runs on a different thread? Where does this code runs? event handler?

Comment: I know it runs on a different thread because the code after the await throws an exception: "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'mainContainer' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on".

Comment: Yes, the code runs in an event handler. I will update my question.

Comment: Which event does `OnHandleCreated` is registered to? Because event handlers in winforms usually have 2 parameters.

Comment: [Control.HandleCreated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handlecreated(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Then the signatures don't match

Comment: I'm overriding `OnHandleCreated` because I'm inheriting form [`Form`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Well, you either found a bug in .Net or you're missing something. What's `DoSomethingAsync`?

Comment: @i3arnon: see my updated question.

Comment: @AJRichardson, can you consistently reproduce the issue? Does omitting the call to `Controls.Add()` *always* result in the post-await part running on the wrong thread, and does adding the former *always* result in the latter running on the right thread?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yes

Comment: Dark magic is definitely at play, then. Sure, you're asking for trouble by overriding a method linked to a native event handler and making it async at the same time. I don't know how the runtime will handle this situation. Then again, the behavior of `Controls.Add()` is quite peculiar indeed.

Comment: @AJRichardson Can you check what's in `SynchronizationContext.Current` before and after the `await`?

Comment: What if you minimize your async void OnHandleCreated method and move all the code into an async Task OnHandleCreatedAsync, as suggested in [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)?

Comment: @i3arnon How do I check the contents of `SynchronizationContext.Current`? It's just an object with some methods but no properties.

Comment: @AJRichardson what matters is whether that is null or not. Is it null before or after the await?

Comment: @i3arnon No, it is never null.

Comment: @AJRichardson that means that in both cases you are running on the UI thread. Are you sure you're getting that exception there?

Comment: I checked `Thread.Current` and it is different before and after the await (in the first case only).

Comment: There is definitely dark magic involved with the `HandleCreated` event. I switched to using the `Load` event, and everything works fine. I'm not sure why `HandleCreated` was being used, anyways. (I inherited this code from others, and a lot of it is very messy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>It appears that something strange is happening with `OnHandleCreated`. My solution was to use `OnLoad` instead. I'm pretty happy with this solution because there is really no reason to use `OnHandleCreated` in my situation.</strike>

I'm still curious as to why this is happening, so if anyone knows, feel free to post another answer.

Edit:

I found the real problem: it turns out that I was calling `Form.ShowDialog()` after a `ConfigureAwait(false)`. As such, the form was being constructed on the UI thread, but then I was calling `ShowDialog` on a non-UI thread. I'm surprised that this worked at all.

I've removed the `ConfigureAwait(false)` so now `ShowDialog` is getting called on the UI thread.

Comment: Could you place `Debug.WriteLine(new { SynchronizationContext.Current })` right before `await DoSomethingAsync()` inside `OnHandleCreated`? Does it show `System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` (expected) or `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext` ?

Comment: I get a `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext` before the await, and null after the await. I'm not sure why I was getting a non-null value yesterday. But I guess that explains it.
I also noticed that if I run the same code in the same project on a different branch in our repo, I get a `System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`, and everything works properly. I wonder if it has something to do with the way the form is getting initialized.

Comment: With your recent edit, you should mark your answer as accepted as it explains what actually happened. Otherwise it's safe to use `await` in `OnHandleCreated`, see my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211598/await-without-configureawaitfalse-continues-on-a-different-thread/32213206?noredirect=1#comment52321127_32213644) to Stephen's answer.

Comment: @Noseratio Yeah, I have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer. I will accept it once SO lets me :)

Answer (score 8):

> My understanding was that if I omit ConfigureAwait(false), then the continuation should run on the original thread. Is this incorrect in some situations?

What actually happens is that `await` will capture the current context by default, and use this context to resume the `async` method. This context is `SynchronizationContext.Current`, unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current` (usually the thread pool context). Most of the time, the UI thread has a UI `SynchronizationContext` - in the case of WinForms, an instance of `WinFormsSynchronizationContext`.

> I've also noticed that if I add a control to the collection before the await, then the continuation magically runs on the correct thread.

No thread starts with a `SynchronizationContext` automatically. The WinForms `SynchronizationContext` is installed on-demand when the first control is created. This is why you're seeing it resume on a UI thread after creating a control.

Since moving to `OnLoad` is a workable solution, I recommend you just go with that. The only other option (to resume on the UI thread before a control is created) is to manually create a control before your first `await`.

Comment: Actually, `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` gets installed in `Control`'s constructor [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,535), so it should be there already when `OnHandleCreated` is called. This has to be something else. There's a possibly related [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806432/application-doevents-resets-the-threads-current-synchronization-context), but in that case both `OnHandleCreated` and `OnLoad` would be affected.