# Await continuing on worker thread even with no call to ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have an async function that is being awaited from the UI thread. I am certain `ConfigureAwait(false)` is not being called. In fact I've tried explicitly calling `ConfigureAwait(true)` just to be sure. However, when the awaited Task finishes it is continuing on a worker thread. After some digging I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211598/await-without-configureawaitfalse-continues-on-a-different-thread) question, which at least pointed me toward a possible cause. I added

```
var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
var scheduler = TaskScheduler.Current;
```

just before the awaited function so I could see if the TaskAwaiter was able to capture the context. It seems the context is null but the scheduler is assigned a valid reference. However, when the awaited task completed it was still continuing on a worker thread. So I dug a little more.

Using Resharper I found this little gem in `Task.SetContinuationForAwait`:

```
// If the user wants the continuation to run on the current "context" if there is one...
if (continueOnCapturedContext)
{
    // First try getting the current synchronization context.
    // If the current context is really just the base SynchronizationContext type, 
    // which is intended to be equivalent to not having a current SynchronizationContext at all, 
    // then ignore it.  This helps with performance by avoiding unnecessary posts and queueing
    // of work items, but more so it ensures that if code happens to publish the default context 
    // as current, it won't prevent usage of a current task scheduler if there is one.
    var syncCtx = SynchronizationContext.CurrentNoFlow;
    if (syncCtx != null && syncCtx.GetType() != typeof(SynchronizationContext))
    {
        tc = new SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation(syncCtx, continuationAction, flowExecutionContext, ref stackMark);
    }
    else
    {
        // If there was no SynchronizationContext, then try for the current scheduler.
        // We only care about it if it's not the default.
        var scheduler = TaskScheduler.InternalCurrent;
        if (scheduler != null && scheduler != TaskScheduler.Default)
        {
            tc = new TaskSchedulerAwaitTaskContinuation(scheduler, continuationAction, flowExecutionContext, ref stackMark);
        }
    }
}
```

I set break points on the two if statements and found that both `syncCtx` and `scheduler` were null so this explains why the awaited task was continuing on a worker thread but it doesn't explain why `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null on the UI thread or why `TaskScheduler.Current` is null at the point the continuation is about to be invoked.

Comment: Most probably you were not running on the UI thread when before awaiting. What is the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread`?

Comment: It is `false` and the Managed Id is 1, matching the Main Thread listed in the Threads window. I'm certain the await is taking place from the UI thread.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a small example?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've tried reproducing the problem in a throw away application but so far no luck.

Comment: What's the type of SynchronizationContext.Current at the point this happens? What's TaskScheduler.Current?; Maybe you can reproduce by deleting code until the issue disappears.

Comment: What is your project type? WinForm, WPF ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was a result of attempting to use a class library containing WPF forms from a native Win32 application. An ordinary WinForms or WPF application would initialize the `SynchronizationContext` in the constructor of `Control`. This would normally occur during the creating of the "parking" form.

For reasons I can't yet explain, no matter how many controls are created, the `SynchronizationContext` is never initialized. Manually creating it some time before any of the forms are created allows `await`ed tasks to continue on the correct thread.

```
if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null)
{
    AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
}
```

Comment: I believe WPF only installs its `SynchronizationContext` in its main loop (dispatcher's pushframe or whatever). This makes a lot more sense to me than WinForm's habit of installing its `SyncCtx` on any thread that happens to construct a UI handle.